# Mercurial how to ignore pom.xml file locally

Tags: maven, mercurial

I'm trying to ignore a `pom.xml` file [locally without making any commits](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only), but don't know why hgignore doesn't work.

1. Add the following lines in `.hg/hgrc`

   ```
   [ui]
   ignore = repo/.hg/hgignore
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   echo "pom.xml" >> .hg/hgignore
   ```

Then `pom.xml` file still isn't ignored:

```
hg status
M pom.xml
```

How can I ignore the `pom.xml` file locally without making any commits?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `ui.ignore` says:

> Filenames are relative to the repository root.

So you want the following in `.hg/hgrc` (not `.hg/hgignore`, I assume that was a typo in your question):

```
[ui]
ignore = .hg/hgignore
```

Appears to work ("relative to the repository root"), however, according to [mecurial tips and tricks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only) (and confirmed with a simple test), it doesn't work from subdirectories of the repository.
Their recommendation/work-around is to specify the full path (e.g. `ignore = /full/path/to/repository/.hg/hgignore`).

This will ignore *untracked* files (i.e. new files).
Just like the regular repository's `.hgignore`.
However, it will not ignore modifications to files that already exist in the repository (such as your "M pom.xml" line indicates).

From `hg help hgignore` (emphasis added):

> The Mercurial system uses a file called ".hgignore" in the root directory
>       of a repository to control its behavior when it searches for **files that it
>       is not currently tracking**.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've edited the question. So is there no way to do that?

Comment: @dimo414, I've added the tips&trick link and corrected my post from the information in it; thanks! Perhaps you should have edited/commented on this answer rather than editing that link into the question?

Comment: @nguyenngoc101, I don't think there is an easy way, at least none I'm aware of. But I'm by no means an exhaustive expert. I actually made the answer before I noticed the "M" and that those weren't ignored and edited that info in later.